# Consuming JSON response to Deserialize

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I'm getting a response in JSON and I'm trying to use the

```vb
 DeserializeStoreInfoResponse(Storeresponse As String) As String
    Dim obj As New JSON_resultStorePos
    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_resultStorePos)(Storeresponse)
```

the initial response is a HttpResponseMessage and all I need is the JSON string info.  When it's a nice neat string in Json format everything deserializes fine into the JSON_resultStorePos table.  But I'm trying to view the initial response to see if everything is there in their response and can't quite figure out where the actual JSON content is written in the HttpResponseMessage?

here's some of the response:

```
?aResponse
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Pragma: no-cache
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2016 13:37:39 GMT
  Set-Cookie: SERVERID=04-97JSNQEU5RG2G; path=/; HttpOnly
  Server: Apache
  X-Powered-By: Express
  Content-Length: 71
  Content-Type: application/json

?aResponse.Content
{System.Net.Http.StreamContent}
    Headers: {Content-Length: 71
Content-Type: application/json
}
    IsBuffered: True
    bufferSize: 4096
    bufferedContent: {System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LimitMemoryStream}
    canCalculateLength: True
    content: {System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream}
    contentConsumed: True
    contentReadStream: Nothing
    disposed: False
    headers: {Content-Length: 71
Content-Type: application/json
```

How can I see the JSON string I'm deserializing ?

Comment: When you call DeserializeObject you seem to be passing a string, you could output Storeresponse. Or check out the Content property of HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: thanks Lotus  TheMktResponse = Await aResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    'MsgBox(TheStoreResponse)
                    'This will grab the response content and load into the 
                    RespMsg = DeserializeMktBsktResponse(TheMktResponse)